# while loop freezed my windows UI and not window gets hanged

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

I have written while loop to read data from InPutStream and saving it in string.

But when reading is done, UI of my windows app gets freezes or hanged.

I have used InputSteam and Scanner class to read the data.

Here is the code which I have used,

```
              try{
                   // trying to send command to scanner to start scan
                   String strPushButtonCommand = "xx";
                   byte [] mValue = strPushButtonCommand.getBytes();
                   mOutPut.write(mValue);
                   writeToFile = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(filepath+ 
                                                                   ".txt"));
                   InputStream mInput = chosenPort.getInputStream();
                   Scanner input = new Scanner(mInput);
                            while(input.hasNextLine())
                            { 
                                data = input.nextLine();
                                System.out.println(data);
                                writeToFile.write(data+"\n");
                            }
                   input.close();
                   System.out.println("print this message");

                    }catch(Exception error){
                   System.out.println(error);
               }
```

In this case while loop does not come out of loop.

Comment: _In this case while loop does not come out of loop_ doesn't this answer your question?

Comment: Which UI? cmd or an IDE? Do you see lines being printed or not? What is the size of the file you're reading from?

Comment: IDE one.. I am using Eclipse IDE for my application. Actually it is reading data from hardware device